# Wifi default gateway still shows up after wifi disconnect and deleting destinationcache

Tags: windows, routing

Trying to understand what is going on with default routes on windows after having disconnected from a wifi with this little piece of code :

```
echo "=> Clearing the destinationcache cache ..."
gsudo.exe netsh interface ip delete destinationcache

echo '=> Printing default routes via "route print" ...'
route print | sls "Netmask|0.0.0.0.*0.0.0.0"

echo ''
echo '=> Printing default routes via "Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0" ...'
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 | Out-String -Stream

echo '=> Printing default routes via "netsh int ip sh route" ...'
echo ''
netsh int ip sh route | sls "Prefix|0.0.0.0/0"
```

And I get this output :

```
=> Clearing the destinationcache cache ...
Ok.

=> Printing default routes via "route print" ...

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.20.24.1      10.20.24.14     35

=> Printing default routes via "Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0" ...

ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric ifMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                              -------                                  ----------- -------- -----------
12      0.0.0.0/0                                      172.20.88.1                                        0 40       ActiveStore
24      0.0.0.0/0                                      10.20.24.1                                         0 35       ActiveStore


=> Printing default routes via "netsh int ip sh route" ...

Publish  Type      Met  Prefix                    Idx  Gateway/Interface Name
No       Manual    0    0.0.0.0/0                  24  10.20.24.1
No       Manual    0    0.0.0.0/0                  12  172.20.88.1
```

After disconnecting from a WiFi network and deleting the destinationcache cache,  there should be only one line also for `Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0` and `netsh int ip sh route`.

What is going on here ?